# Integration with Limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Find $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx$$

Now, the solution was hinted like this:

using the property $$f(x)=f(2a-x)$$ the limit becomes half

$$2 \displaystyle \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0} (x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} dx$$.....$$(1)$$

plz see carefully.

for $$x\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$$

$$x$$ has smaller value than $$(1-x)$$.

taking common $$(1-x)^{n}$$ in $$(1)$$

also $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{x}{1-x})^{n} \rightarrow 0$$

the integral reduces to

$$2 \displaystyle \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0} (1-x) \times (1^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}.dx$$

$$2 \displaystyle \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0} (1-x).dx$$

$$\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: hint: Use Dini's theorem.

Comment: The first property is that if $f(x)=(x^n+(1-x)^n)^{1/n}$ then $f(x)=f(1-x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: The property I wrote down has nothing to do with integrals, definite or otherwise. But it happens to be applied here to a definite integral.

Comment: No, it's valid whenever it's valid. In particular, it's valid for any function that is symmetric in $x$ and $1-x$. It would be valid for $\sin x\sin(1-x)$, and for $e^{x(1-x)}$, and for $\log(x^2+1)+\log((1-x)^2+1)$, and so on.

Comment: If you want to be sure that I see a comment directed to me, you have to put @Gerry in there somewhere. But of course you can make use of any such symmetry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y=(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=(1-x)\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Now, in $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$
$$0\leq \frac{x}{1-x} \leq 1$$
$$0\leq \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{n} \leq 1$$
$$1\leq \left(1+\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$(1-x)\leq y \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-x)$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)dx \leq \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} y\:dx \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)dx$$
$$\frac{3}{8} \leq \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} y\:dx \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{3}{8}$$
for $x$ tending to infinity  $2^{\frac{1}{n}}$ tends to $1$. So, the limit is :
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} y\:dx =\frac{3}{8}$$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_{0}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx=2\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx=\frac{3}{4}$$
In addition. A detailed answer to the question raised in several remarks : How to prove the last equation above ?

$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx$, with change of variable $x=(1-X)$ or $X=(1-x)$ , then $dx=-dX$. The lower bounday $x=\frac{1}{2}$ becomes $X=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, the upper boundary $x=1$ becomes $X=1-1=0$.
$$
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx= \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0}((1-X)^{n}+(1-(1-X))^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}(-dX)$$
$$
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx= -\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0}((1-X)^{n}+X^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dX= \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0}((1-X)^{n}+X^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dX
$$
A basic property of the defined integrals : one can change the symbol of the dummy variable without changing the value of the integral. So, one is allowed to remplace $X$ by $x$ or any other symbol.
$$
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx= \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0}((1-x)^{n}+x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx=\frac{3}{8}
$$
$$
\int^{1}_{0}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx= \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{8}=\frac{3}{4}
$$

Comment: The condition $0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}$ is necessary to have $0\leq\frac{x}{1-x}\leq 1$ which is the strarting point for the proof. In fact, I started to look for what happens if $0\leq\frac{x}{1-x}\leq 1$

Comment: Of course, first you have to prove that  $\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{0}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^{n}+(1-x)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dx$. To do that, change the variable $x$ of the second integral into $(1-x)$.

Comment: $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 (x^n+(1-x)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}dx = \int^{1-1}_{1-\frac{1}{2}} ((1-x)^n+(1-(1-x))^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}(-dx) =\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} ((1-x)^n+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} dx$ is a very simple and typical change of variable

Comment: @Better World : See the detailed explanation, now in addition to my main answer.

Comment: Look at the end of my main answer : a detailed explanation has been added for the change of variable with change of symbol. If you don't know how to made a change of variable without changing the symbol of the variable, use the elementary method of change of variable with a different symbol for the new variable.